# C++ windows form - How to show/hide a certain object (such as a button or textbox) after clicking a button?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In my windows form application, I would like to show or hide a textbox after clicking a button, for example after clicking "OK" button the textbox should disappear and appear again when I click another button.

can someone please help me on how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

use ShowWindow() function with SW_SHOW  or SW_HIDE according to requirement.
Here is the article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx